mongoDB how to populate sub sub document?
I have a Node.js application with a MongoDB database and using mongoose to interact with it.
I have two important schemas:
First is the product schema
export const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  amazon_listing: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "AmazonListing" },
  ...
})


The second is my amazon listing schema, which is made up of a few schemas (not sure if this is an antipattern?)
export const amazonListingSchema = new Schema({
  asin: { type: String, required: true },
  fee_details: { type: feeDetailsSchema },
  ...
})

const feeDetailsSchema = new Schema({
  fees: [{ type: feeArraySchema }],
  ...
})

const feeArraySchema = new Schema({
  type: { type: String },
  amount: { type: Number },
  final_fee: { type: Number },
  promotion: { type: Number },
})


When I query for all my products, I also want to populate the amazon_listing.fee_details.fees but I can't figure out how.
I have tried the following approach:
    return ProductModel.find({})
      .sort(sortOrder)
      .populate("amazon_listing")
      .populate("amazon_listing.fee_details.fees")
      .exec()

but each time when I inspect the network traffic my response is:
       "fee_details": {
          ...
          "fees": [
            {
              "_id": "663fc68f066f091f9b029857"
            },
            {
              "_id": "663fc68f066f091f9b029858"
            },
            {
              "_id": "663fc68f066f091f9b029859"
            },
            {
              "_id": "663fc68f066f091f9b02985a"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "663fc68f066f091f9b029856"
        }


Any help and links to documentation would be great, thanks.


The second is my amazon listing schema, which is made up of a few schemas (not sure if this is an antipattern?):

Re: This is quite normal, the schema types can be based on another schema.

When I query for all my products, I also want to populate the amazon_listing.fee_details.fees but I can't figure out how.

return ProductModel.find({}) .sort(sortOrder) .populate("amazon_listing") .populate("amazon_listing.fee_details.fees") .exec()

Re: In the code above, amazon_listing is a reference key, it refers to another model which is AmazonListing. Therefore the first populate call - populate("amazon_listing")  is valid. However the second populate call - populate("amazon_listing.fee_details.fees") is to be reviewed.
It tries to populate the key fees. Please look at the schema type of this key, it is like this - fees: [{ type: feeArraySchema }]. It means it is not a reference type key instead it is an array of embedded sub-documents of feeArraySchema. It further means it is already available as part of the populated document - amazon_listing. Therefore the find call is complete with the statement - ProductModel.find({}) .sort(sortOrder) .populate("amazon_listing").exec().
Now once the documents are retrieved by find method, the key fees can be accessed through dot notation just as an embedded document like this - ProductModelDocument.amazon_listing.fee_details.fees.  Please refer to the sample code enclosed below, it has the relevant codes, please take a close look at the lines line1 and line2. It implement what has been discussed so far.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

run().catch((e) => console.log(e));

async function run() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

  const feeArraySchema = new Schema({
    type: { type: String },
    amount: { type: Number },
    final_fee: { type: Number },
    promotion: { type: Number },
  });

  const feeDetailsSchema = new Schema({
    fees: [{ type: feeArraySchema }],
  });

  const amazonListingSchema = new Schema({
    asin: { type: String, required: true },
    fee_details: { type: feeDetailsSchema },
  });

  const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    amazon_listing: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AmazonListing' },
  });

  const AmazonListing = mongoose.model('AmazonListing', amazonListingSchema);
  await AmazonListing.deleteMany();
  const amazon = await new AmazonListing({
    asin: 'asin',
    fee_details: {
      fees: [{ type: 'type', amount: 1, final_fee: 2, promotion: 3 }],
    },
  }).save();

  const ProductList = mongoose.model('ProductList', productSchema);
  await ProductList.deleteMany();
  await new ProductList({ name: 'name', amazon_listing: amazon._id }).save();

// line1
 const docs = await ProductList.find().populate('amazon_listing');
// line2
  docs.forEach((d) => {
    console.log(d);
    console.log(d.amazon_listing.fee_details.fees);
  });
}

OUTPUT:
{
  _id: new ObjectId('6641e74c75090d74618c997a'),
  name: 'name',
  amazon_listing: {
    _id: new ObjectId('6641e74c75090d74618c9975'),
    asin: 'asin',
    fee_details: { fees: [Array], _id: new ObjectId('6641e74c75090d74618c9976') },
    __v: 0
  },
  __v: 0
}
[
  {
    type: 'type',
    amount: 1,
    final_fee: 2,
    promotion: 3,
    _id: new ObjectId('6641e74c75090d74618c9977')
  }
]

